# Many rectangles in a container - when changing the size of one of them, others must compensate

Tags: javascript

Let's consider the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/m0gxgu21/

```
// See the full commented code and a visual example in the JSFiddle
var rects = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, w: 120, h: 120 },
    { x: 120, y: 0, w: 100, h: 40 },
    { x: 220, y: 0, w: 100, h: 120 },
    { x: 120, y: 40, w: 100, h: 80 },
    { x: 0, y: 120, w: 180, h: 60 },
    { x: 180, y: 120, w: 140, h: 60 }
];

function redraw() {
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        $('#rect-' + i).css({
            left: rects[i].x,
            top: rects[i].y,
            width: rects[i].w,
            height: rects[i].h
        });
    }
}

redraw();

// Now we increase the size of a rectangle
var d = 20;
rects[3].w += d;
rects[3].h += d;

redraw();
```

We want to resize any one of the given rectangles. Here are the rules:

- the originally resized rectangle should stay centered (similar to transform-origin: 50% 50%;)
- other rectangles should reduce their size to make room for the resized rect.
- no rectangles can overlap
- no rectangles can leave the bounds of the container, including the resized rect.
- rectangles can change their aspect ratio

**This is what must NOT happen:**

[image]

Here is a visual representation of what must happen:

[image]

Left is before resizing, right is after.

**IT WORKS!!!**

Here are two examples and the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/02s5s5pa/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/9sh4nL46/1/

Comment: Top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left are not rectangles.

Comment: See the JSFiddle. They are rectangles, but they overlap. This image is an example of what doesn't need to happen.

Comment: This isn't that easy, for starters, the scanline algorithm can be used to determine which rectangles overlap.

Comment: @simonzack - Not necessary.  Before the rectangles are resized, you know which borders are shared with others, so you know which rectangles to adjust and by how much.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov - You should have a method called `resize(rect, dw, dh)` to handle this, so it can measure the initial conditions and adjust the `rects` array as necessary.

Comment: @StevenMoseley There might be some simpler way for this, but knowing the borders is not enough. Imagine when there are lots of rectangles, and you resize the middle rectangle by say 2x, it will overlap with lots of retangles on it's bottom right, and it's not easy to tell which ones it overlaps with.

Comment: @simonzack - Good point.

Comment: Actually scanline is not needed since it is known they do not previously overlap, you only need to check whether each rectangle overlap with the resized rectangle.

Comment: I think I have an idea in my head that I will try to implement a bit later. What if we divide the grid in 8 rectangles, each touching one of the edges of the resized rectangle and the corresponding wall of the grid. Then, after the rectangle is resized we take each of the 8 rects and scale them back (along with all coordinates contained in them) so they fit the container again?

Comment: Is it only the center rect you're resizing, or can it be any?

Comment: @Rudie it can be any. I think I figured it out, thought. Take a look at the newest image in the question. If we take the center of the resized rect and multiply each point by a vector pointing at the closest corner of the container (and decreases in length as it approaches the corner) that might produce exactly the expected result. I will play with the implementation a bit later and post updates.

Comment: I thought free space wasn't allowed. If free space is allowed, it's much easier. If any rect can change, it's harder. If more than 3 rects can be on 1 axis, it's harder again. I'm very curious to see the result.

Comment: @Rudie You can imagine there was a rectangle in the free space, it makes to difference to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to want the flexibility to shrink the items on the side, you'll need to be able to specify the origin point for the scaling - you've spec'ed center point expansion, but that doesn't account for a rectangle that's scaled from the side.

That said, I'd process x and y separately.  This also enables you to expand into a z axis down the road.  To do that, I'd change "w" to "xl" (x length).  Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/m0gxgu21/14/

```
var rects = [
    { x: 0, y: 0, xl: 120, yl: 60 },
    { x: 120, y: 0, xl: 100, yl: 40 },
    { x: 220, y: 0, xl: 100, yl: 120 },
    { x: 120, y: 40, xl: 100, yl: 80 },
    { x: 0, y: 120, xl: 180, yl: 40 },
    { x: 180, y: 120, xl: 140, yl: 60 }
],
    current = 3
    canvas = { x: 320, y: 180 };

function resize(size) {
    size = size || { x: 20, y: 20 };
    var c = {
            x: rects[current].x,
            y: rects[current].y,
            xl: rects[current].xl,
            yl: rects[current].yl
        };
        c.x2 = c.x + c.xl;
        c.y2 = c.y + c.yl;
        c.xm = c.x + c.xl/2;
        c.ym = c.y + c.yl/2;
    for (var i in rects) {
        if (i != current) {
            position( rects[i], c, size, [ 'x', 'y' ] );
            position( rects[i], c, size, [ 'x', 'y' ], true );
        }
    }
    changeSize(size);
    redraw();
}
var position = function( r, c, size, dim, point2 ) {
        var ratio = 1,
            percent = 0;
        for (var index in dim) {
            var d = dim[index],
                point = r[d];
            if (point2) point = point + r[d + 'l'];
            if ( point >= canvas[d] ) {
                point = canvas[d];
            } else {
                if (point <= c[d]) {
                    ratio = (c[d] - size[d]/2) /c[d];
                    point *= ratio;
                } else if (point <= c[d + 'm']) {
                    ratio = (c[d+'l'] + size[d]) /c[d+'l'];
                    point = c[d + 'm'] - ((c[d + 'm'] - point) * ratio);
                } else if (point <= c[d+'2']) {
                    ratio = (c[d+'l'] + size[d]) /c[d+'l'];
                    point = c[d + 'm'] - ((c[d + 'm'] - point) * ratio);
                } else if (point <= canvas[d]) {
                    ratio = ((canvas[d] - c[d+'2']) - size[d]/2) / (canvas[d] - c[d+'2']);
                    point = c[d+'2'] + ratio * ( point - c[d+'2'] );
                }
            }
                if (point2) {
                    if ( point > canvas[d] ) point = canvas[d];
                    r[d + 'l'] = parseInt(point - r[d]);
                } else {
                    r[d] = point > 0 ? parseInt(point):0;
                }
        };
};

function redraw() {
    for (var i in rects) {
        $('#rect-' + i).css({
            left: rects[i].x,
            top: rects[i].y,
            width: rects[i].xl,
            height: rects[i].yl
        });
    }
}

redraw();

var changeSize = function(size) {
    rects[current].x += -size.x/2;
    rects[current].y += -size.y/2;
    rects[current].xl += size.x;
    rects[current].yl += size.y;
};

$('button.smaller').click( function(){ resize({ x:-20, y: -20 }) } );
$('button.bigger').click( function(){ resize() } );
```

The shapes get a little off if you go back and forth, so it needs some fine-tuning, but I'm out of time and thought this might get you a little further along.  It also needs a max-size for the adjusted div, and it should auto-generate the divs from the rects array.  You probably also should impose a grid to snap the rectangles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I already managed to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/02s5s5pa/2/

Comment: If you set the "debug" var to "true" you will get an idea of how it works. Basically I take the original rect and divide the rest of the space in 8 quadrants around it. I then scale the quadrants along with any coordinates they contain. And that's pretty much it :)

Comment: Both your solutions are cool, but both don't keep the ouside boundaries fixed. Nikolay's looks cooler, but it has some weird unnecessary movements. I'm going to make an attempt soon too, just for fun of course. Math is that.

Comment: I like the way your's moves, @NikolayDyankov.

Comment: @Rudie, I like the unnecessary movements.  It's kinda quirky.  Depends what you're trying to do, though.  I'd say Nikolay's fits inside the original outer boundaries.  The object as a whole doesn't increase in size (at least not appreciably).

Comment: @Rudie Actually if you set a background to the .container object you will see that all rects stay within the boundaries :)

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Yes, within, but not ON. The outside boundaries of the outside elements shouldn't change, but they wobble. I don't think ratios and vectors are the best solution. The result is hard px, so the calculation should be hard px IMO. Maybe later =)

Comment: IMO, I'd calculate the ratios, THEN convert to hard px.  This would also allow you to set minimum grid sizes using the same mechanism.   Clearly, the script I wrote needs refinement to properly fill the gaps, but that's how the ratios are applied, not how the calculations are made (unless my calculations are off).  All this said, I'd probably use a shuffle mechanism like masonry.js (http://masonry.desandro.com/), instead of the current resize.  Though, that might not work if you're doing a rollover.